# Jackson deserializing inner custom class object

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have a class similar to

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String itemName;
    public User owner;
}
```

and I get the json data from an api similar to

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "itemName": "theItem",
    "owner": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "theUser"
    }
}
```

I have an object mapper to convert json data to "Item" object.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

final Item item = mapper.readValue(data, Item.class);
```

But the values of owner.id and owner.name is null as it was not able to deserialize json inside the json. what is the solution to deserialize the internal custom objects?

Comment: This seems to work fine. I tried with Jackson 1.9.13 (as you are using a version < 2). Could you specify which exact version you are using and if `mapper` has any other configuration ? Also confirm that you are importing the correct `User` and `Item` classes in the file where you are deserializing.

Comment: I am using the same version. But it didn't work for me. Yes, I was importing the correct classes. I tried mapping the objects with Gson. It seems to work fine. So, i just replaced jackson with Gson in my application. But still trying to figure out why it didn't work though. I don't have any other configuration for mapper in my application.